# undefined reference to `tcp_connect`

Tags: gnutls

Tried to compile gnutls examples. x509 client showed error on compilation.

```
gcc ex-client-x509.c -o ex-client-x509 -lgnutls
```

Error :

```
anupam_on@HP530Notebook:~/Dev/gnutls-3.3.9/doc/examples$ gcc ex-client-x509.c -o ex-client-x509 -lgnutls
/tmp/cc0Nmw0a.o: In function `main':
ex-client-x509.c:(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `tcp_connect'
ex-client-x509.c:(.text+0x34f): undefined reference to `tcp_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`-lgnutls` is the `LD` flag that I use. But still error.

Answer (score 1):

Helper functions for TCP connect and close are provided in a standalone [HTML document](https://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Helper-functions-for-TCP-connections.html).

That way they don't need to be repeated in every GnuTLS example.